# Validating phone number in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, phone-number

What are the rules for validating a North American phone number? Also, is there a `regex` I can use? Is there a gem to do this?

Here are few rules I have in mind

1. A 10 digit number
2. no special characters
3. A positive number

Comment: Do read [US Phone Number Verification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175488/us-phone-number-verification). Also [Is there a gem that normalizes and format US phone numbers in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912690/is-there-a-gem-that-normalizes-and-format-us-phone-numbers-in-ruby) is not a duplicate but may have useful information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many gems that will do this for you.

Take a look at: http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=phone+number

This one looks like it will do what you need -- it essentially implements a regex to validate the phone number: http://rubygems.org/gems/validates_phone_number

For US, Canada (Bermuda, Bahamas... etc and all +1 numbers) there are other rules that the regex should follow. The first digit (after the +1) must be 2-9.

For a full list see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan

Comment: The validates_phone_number gem requires rails which may be a gotcha for OP.

Comment: That gem permits numbers like 911 555 1234, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**

```
(?:\+?|\b)[0-9]{10}\b
```

**Explanation**

```
@"
(?:         # Match the regular expression below
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \+          # Match the character “+” literally
         ?           # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \b          # Assert position at a word boundary
)
[0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   {10}        # Exactly 10 times
\b          # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Answer (score 4):

The rules I used in [my perl code](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Number-Phone-2.0/lib/Number/Phone/NANP.pm) for validating NANP phone numbers came from an email sent by Doug Newell to the telnum-l mailing list, which I reproduce below, somewhat simplified to only consider full 10 digit numbers:

```
The number 10 digits long.  We'll call this pattern:
    ABC DEF XXXX

A may not be 0 or 1.

B may not be 9.

A+B may not be 37 or 96.

B+C may not be 11.

D may not be 0 or 1.
```

You may be able to extract a regex from [libphonenumber's](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) metadata, but beware, it is GNARLY AS HELL.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a gem here: https://github.com/travisjeffery/validates_phone_number that will do what you want, if you have any questions or issues let me know, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more advanced than a regex, [Twilio has an API that can do this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/04/validate-phone-numbers-in-ruby-using-the-lookup-api.html):

> Twilio Lookup is a REST API that can:
>
> Verify that a phone number exists
>
> Format any international phone
>   number into its local standard
>
> Determine if a phone number is a cell
>   phone, VOIP or landline
>
> Discover information about a phone number’s
>   carrier

I haven't used this yet! But it should work, though you do need a (free) Twilio account. (Also I'm not affiliated with Twilio, other than having a free account I'm playing with.)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Phne
def ad
puts "Enter your phone number"
re=gets.chomp
if re= ~/\b^([0-9]{10})$\b/
puts "Valid phone number"
else
puts "Invalid phone number"
end
end
end

obj=Phne.new
obj.ad
```