# Capture a phone with regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to capture spanish phone numbers that can have these forms:

- 123456789
- 123 45 67 89
- 123.45.67.89
- 123-45-67-89

I'm using this regular expression in ruby:

```
text.match(/([6][0-9]+\s?\-?\.?[0-9]*\s?\-?\.?[0-9]*\s?\-?\.?[0-9]*)/)
```

The problem is that it also captures other numbers in the text. Specifically I'd like to capture all 9 numbers starting by 6 that can be separated by white spaces, dashes, or dots; and not surrounded by other numbers (as sometimes I have big references like ref:3453459680934983).

Any clue?

Lots of thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848748/validating-phone-number-in-ruby ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation. This isn't as easy as you assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
^6(\d{8}|(\d{2}((\s|\.|-)\d{2}){3}))$
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I changed it a bit, so it can be surrounded by other digits and add two more cases, but this syntax helped me a lot. Thanks!

My end solution: /6(\d{8}|(\d{2}((\s|\.|-)\d{2}){3})|(\d{2}(\s|\.|-)\d{6})|\d{2}((\s|\.|-)\d{3}){2})/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{3}(?:(?:[ \.\-]?)\d{2}){3}$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lD3yY0/1)**

[image]

By the way, if you want to match the last numbers an enforce to start by `6` you can use:

```
6\d{2}(?:(?:[ \.\-]?)\d{2}){3}$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lD3yY0/2)**

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`text.match(/^[0-9]{3}\s*[\-\.]?(?:[0-9]{2}\s*[\-\.]?){3}$/)`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to match those characters is easy:

```
/[\d .-]+/
```

http://rubular.com/r/hSj7okaji3

You can make it a little more comprehensive and look for digits and separators in certain positions:

```
/6(?:\d{8}|\d{2}[ .-](?:\d{2}[ .-]){2}\d{2})/
```

http://rubular.com/r/HkSp8qk0ph

For instance:

```
strings = [
  'foo 623456789 bar',
  'foo 123456789 bar',
  'foo 623 45 67 89 bar',
  'foo 123 45 67 89 bar',
  'foo 623.45.67.89 bar',
  'foo 123.45.67.89 bar',
  'foo 623-45-67-89 bar',
  'foo 123-45-67-89 bar',
]

found_pns = strings.select{ |s| s[/6(?:\d{8}|\d{2}[ .-](?:\d{2}[ .-]){2}\d{2})/] }
# => ["foo 623456789 bar",
#     "foo 623 45 67 89 bar",
#     "foo 623.45.67.89 bar",
#     "foo 623-45-67-89 bar"]
```

Once you have the numbers, typically you should normalize them prior to storing in a database:

```
found_pns.map{ |s| s[/6(?:\d{8}|\d{2}[ .-](?:\d{2}[ .-]){2}\d{2})/].tr(' .-', '') }
# => ["623456789", "623456789", "623456789", "623456789"]
```

Once you've done that, then you format them as needed when you get ready to display them:

```
pn = "623456789".match(/(?<n1>\d{3})(?<n2>\d{2})(?<n3>\d{2})(?<n4>\d{2})/)
# => #<MatchData "623456789" n1:"623" n2:"45" n3:"67" n4:"89">
```

(I'm using named captures above, but that's just to illustrate how the values are retrieved.)

```
"%s-%s-%s-%s" % [*pn.captures] # => "623-45-67-89"
```

or:

```
pn.captures.join('-') # => "623-45-67-89"
```