# What's the best ruby gem for parsing international phone number?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, phone-number

I need a library to help with parsing international phone number. I tried a couple of them like phone_number, phone, phony, and phoney. After playing with them the whole afternoon, none of them is perfect or as good as Google's libphonenumber (Java though). However, I am forced to choose one for my current project so I go with phoney gem, which seems active and provides more international support. Does anyone know anything better?

There was a similar question below but it's more than a year ago and focused on US phone numbers.

[Is there a gem that normalizes and format US phone numbers in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912690/is-there-a-gem-that-normalizes-and-format-us-phone-numbers-in-ruby)

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you want to do this?

Comment: Create a social app that can find friends by local address book.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Phoner](https://github.com/carr/phone).  It seems to parse both US and international numbers well.

Comment: Check out rules in phoner https://github.com/carr/phone/blob/master/data/phone_countries.yml and rules in phoney https://github.com/habermann24/phoney/blob/master/lib/data/regions.yml. The latter provides more details.

Answer (score 1):

The most current and supported (as for now) is https://github.com/floere/phony

Also you can have a look on https://github.com/carr/phone and https://github.com/habermann24/phoney/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem called ItuCodes that does basic parsing of country codes, paying special attention to complex cases like North America, Russia & Kazakhstan:
* https://github.com/bowsersenior/itu_codes

ItuCodes does not aim to fully parse area codes for every country code, but such a tool could be built on top of it.